# How can I check if a parameter is a subroutine?

Tags: perl

How can I test if a given parameter is a subroutine?

For example:

```perl
sub foo {
    my $bar = shift;
    if (is_subroutine($bar)) {
        return &$bar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd call this like:

```perl
foo(sub { print "Hi!" }); # prints "Hi!"
foo(123); # Nothing
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some tools to work with references are given in the core [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util)

```
use Scalar::Util qw(reftype);

my $cr = sub { say "hi @_" };

say reftype $cr;  #--> CODE
```

The `reftype` returns `undef` for a variable which isn't a reference so test for that first

```
sub is_subroutine {
    my $rt = reftype $_[0];
    return defined $rt and $rt eq 'CODE'
}
```

(but if this is used only in a short sub like in the question then there's no need for another sub)

Then using [ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref) may be simpler in this case as it returns an empty string for non-reference so you may be able to just do

```
if (ref $var eq 'CODE')
```

Unless, that is, there could be `bless`-ings mixed in, like a blessed code reference or an object acting as a subroutine, for which `ref` returns merely the class's name while `reftype` returns the underlying type.

Many of `Scalar::Util` functions (along with yet others) are available with the experimental core [builtin::](https://perldoc.perl.org/builtin) pragma/namespace in newer Perls, including `reftype` (v5.36)

Comment: `reftype` is also part of the `builtin` namespace introduced in v5.36.

Comment: @briandfoy Indeed, and I meant that but didn't say it.  (Also, even as this is a pragma the "namespace" is a good word to use here) ... edited, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try to dereference the scalar as a subroutine with `&{...}` and then check if the result exists.

```
if (exists &{$bar}) {
  ...
}
```

Also, `$bar()` is not valid syntax for calling a subroutine stored in a scalar reference. You'll need to write either `&{$bar}()` or `$bar->()` (the latter is sugar for the former)

Comment: 1. They don't have `$bar()`; they have `&$bar()`, which is short for `&{$bar}()`. And as you say, that's perfectly valid. /// 2. `&BLOCK()` is not sugar for `EXPR->()`. While both perform the same dereference, a block can contain multiple statements.

Comment: @ikegami I had `$bar()` at one point, but I edited it realizing I missed the `&` on my first pass.

Comment: Ah. Must have been within the first 5 minutes since there's no edits shown.

Comment: `exists &{$bar}` will also catch strings that match the names of known subroutines, which may or may not be what you want

Answer (score 1):

[`Ref::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ref::Util) on CPAN provides dedicated helper functions for each type of reference you may need to identify.

For example, in your case, the `is_coderef` function does exactly what you want:

```
use Ref::Util qw/is_coderef/;

sub foo {
    my $bar = shift;
    if (is_coderef($bar)) {
        return &$bar();
    }
    return 0;
}

foo(sub { print "Hi!" }); # prints "Hi!"
foo(123); # Nothing
```